# How should I create a list that'll be returned when method is called and it contains two lists, each one contains four tuples?

Tags: c#, xaml

I created a method that has two lists; each one has four tuples, and I want the two lists to be returned when the method is called. I tried creating a new list to do so, but it can't accept a tuple into a list. Is there a way to convert a tuple into a list?

How should I create a list that'll be returned when method is called and it contains two lists, each one contains four tuples?

Below is a code similar to what I'm working on:
*Note: the reason I needed to use tuples is to be able to access and display them using `XAML`.

```
var listStudents1 = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>

{

               Tuple.Create("A", "Roya Taymoor", "USA"),

               Tuple.Create("B", "Michael Stevens", "UK" ),

               Tuple.Create("C", "Steve Barnes", "UK" )

};
var listStudnets2 = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>

{

               Tuple.Create("C", "Liam Cook", "USA"),

               Tuple.Create("D", "Arianda Reggi", "France" ),

               Tuple.Create("E", "Amy Ronald", "UK" )

}; 
StudentsLists.Add(listStudents1); //StudentsLists is a previously defnded property/list in the class that accepts string. 
StudentsLists.Add(listStudents2);
return StudentsLists;
```

Comment: Do you want a list of lists returned or a list of tulples? If you want a list of tuples like in your example, you’ll need to loop over both lists and add each tuple from each list to the return list of tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `List<whateverYouWantToReturn>` in your case like this below one.

```
public  List<List<Tuple<string, string, string>>> GetStudents(){
    var listStudents1 = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>

{
    Tuple.Create("A", "Roya Taymoor", "USA"),
    Tuple.Create("B", "Michael Stevens", "UK" ),
    Tuple.Create("C", "Steve Barnes", "UK" )

};
var listStudnets2 = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>

{
  Tuple.Create("C", "Liam Cook", "USA"),
  Tuple.Create("D", "Arianda Reggi", "France" ),
  Tuple.Create("E", "Amy Ronald", "UK" )

};  
    var result = new  List<List<Tuple<string, string, string>>>();
    result.Add(listStudents1);
    result.Add(listStudnets2);
    return result;
}
```